# QtTest dll is missing in Qt5.2.1 unittest project

Tags: qt5

QtTest4.dll missing in my Qt5.2.1 project unittest app project.
How to fix this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

I have that in my Python33\lib\site-packages\pyside directory but not in my Qt5 directory.

Comment: will that QtTest4.dll or cuteTest.dll works for Qt5 projects.?